# Random TokenMismatchException Laravel Handler

Tags: ajax, laravel, exception

How do I resend the ajax request from getting TokenMismatchException?
Currently, this is my code.

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->refresh();
}
```

This is my ajax request

```
      $.ajax({
      url: '/getEventsForRefCode',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: { 
              reference_code: reference_code
            },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
      }
```

I didn't pass any token because I already have these

```
window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
    'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
]) !!};


$.ajaxSetup({
  headers:{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
  });
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to retry the same Ajax call after you get a `TokenMismatchException`? You will need to do this from your frontend.

Comment: yes, exactly. how do i do that then if it's a POST request

Comment: As I said, your backend can't fully handle this. You can return a json response from your backend which states the error and retry the request from your frontend when you detect this backend error.

Comment: @jane, post your front end POST request code

Comment: @Option check it again thank you